# iOS Not seeing expected value from block returned

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code, yet I never see the runStepCountTotal get returned at the end. The total increments, but the last NSLog line is actually returned before the block completes.

I realise I am using the block incorrectly, but wondered if someone would be kind enough to explain to me how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

```
- (NSInteger)getRunSteps
{
__block NSInteger runstepCountTotal = 0;

if([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable])
{
    CMMotionActivityManager *cm = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    CMStepCounter *sc = [[CMStepCounter alloc] init];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    [cm queryActivityStartingFromDate:[self startDateOf6DayAgo] toDate:today toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error){

        for(int i=0;i<[activities count]-1;i++)
        {
            CMMotionActivity *a = [activities objectAtIndex:i];
            if (a.running)
            {
                [sc queryStepCountStartingFrom:a.startDate to:[[activities objectAtIndex:i+1] startDate] toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error)
                {
                    runstepCountTotal = runstepCountTotal+numberOfSteps;
                    NSLog(@"Current Total is %ld",(long)runstepCountTotal);
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
NSLog(@"Final Total is %ld",(long)runstepCountTotal);
return runstepCountTotal;
}
```

Comment: To make it correctly you should not create getter for this purpose. Let the block update the designated property instead

Comment: @voromax please could you explain this further? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for the `queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler:` method.

> **Discussion**
>   This method runs asynchronously, returning immediately and delivering the results to the specified handler block.

Your method returns long before the handler block is called and finished.

Comment: So the queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler returns as expected. I understand that the method returns long before, but would like to understand how I should implement this so enable me to do the loop I am doing, get the total value and return it? I would really appreciate an understanding of how this should work. Thanks.

Comment: You have to implement an asynchronous solution. You can't have a method with a regular return value.

Comment: Hi I am unsure how to do this. As I put on the other answer, if you could explain in more detail I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we should perform some asynchronous method

```
- (void)loadPropertyAsynchronouslyWithCompletion:(void (^)(int val))completion;
```

And some property to update:

```
@property int value;
```

Then to get its value we need something like this:

```
[self loadPropertyAsynchronouslyWithCompletion:^(int val){
    self.value = val;
}];
```

I skipped some multithread specific moments to make the idea more clear

**EDIT**

---

To be closer to your example...

The method to *asynchronously* update some UILabel element of your user interface with the number of steps could be like this:

```
- (void)updateSomeLabel:(UILabel *)label withNumberOfStepsStartingFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate
{
    if (![CMStepCounter isStepCountingAvailable]) {
        return;
    }

    CMStepCounter *stepCounter = [[CMStepCounter alloc] init];

    [stepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:fromDate to:toDate toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fromDate: %@, toDate:%@, numberOfSteps:%d", fromDate, toDate, numberOfSteps];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error:%@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Okay I have tried to understand how to do this with the code above, but failed. Would you mind either explaining further, or showing me how to put it together? If you do put it together, I would appreciate you explaining it to me, as that way I will understand better. Thanks.